# Flask-JWT-Ext get_current_user(), get_jwt_identity() returns None despite having tokens

Tags: flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended, flask-jwt

Thanks for taking a look. I am trying to implement Flask-JWT-Ext. I have redis blacklist implemented in order to revoke my tokens.

I am trying to use get_current_user(), get_jwt_identity() etc but it is returning None, despite passing in the access tokens on with @jwt_required decorator...

Here is my login (which correctly generates access and refresh tokens):

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def check_login_info():
    '''
    Login user
    '''
    arw = ApiResponseWrapper()
    login_data = request.get_json()
    
    try:
        matching_login = Login.query.filter_by(username=login_data['username']).one()
        matching_login.check_password(login_data['password_hash'])

        access_token = create_access_token(identity=matching_login.username)
        access_jti = get_jti(encoded_token=access_token)
        revoked_store.set(access_jti, 'false', timedelta(minutes=15) * 1.2)

        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=matching_login.username)
        refresh_jti = get_jti(encoded_token=refresh_token)
        revoked_store.set(refresh_jti, 'false',  timedelta(days=30) * 1.2)

        tokens = {
            'access_token': access_token,
            'refresh_token': refresh_token
        }

    except (MultipleResultsFound, NoResultFound):
        arw.add_errors('No result found or multiple results found')

    except ValueError:
        arw.add_errors('Value error')

    except BadRequestsError:
        arw.add_errors('Bad requests error')

    if arw.has_errors():
        return arw.to_json(None, 400)

    return jsonify(tokens), 201
```

I wasn't able to use get_current_user(), etc on a different route, so I made a sample one to test it out. It returns None for current user and identity, despite passing in the correct tokens in the header.

```
@jwt_required
@app.route('/check', methods=['GET'])
def check_login():
    current_user = get_current_user()
    user_has_tokens = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify({"user": current_user, "tokens": user_has_tokens}), 201
```

Do you know what I'm missing? I definitely have the redis blacklist set up correctly and generating tokens with create_access_token, etc work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator order is backwards. Put the `app.route` before the `jwt_required`

Comment: I had it that way before. Read somewhere that it needs to be flipped. Anyways was having the same issue with the decorator flipped.